# Accessing non tree structured xml data in python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have several xml files that I want to parse in python. I am aware of the ElementTree package in python, however my xml files aren't stored in a tree like structure. Below is an example

```
<tag1 attribute1="at1" attribute2="at2">My files are text that I annotated with a tool 
to create these xml files.</tag1>
Some parts of the text are enclosed in an xml tag, whereas others are not. 
<tag1 attribute1="at1" attribute2="at2"><tag2 attribute3="at3" attribute4="at4">Some
are even enclosed in multiple tags.</tag1></tag2>
And some have overlapping tags:
<tag1 attribute1="at1" attribute2="at2">This is an example sentence
<tag3 attribute5="at5">containing a nested example sentence</tag3></tag1>
```

Whenever I use an ElementTree like function to parse the file, I can only access the very first tag. I am looking for a way to parse all the tags and don't want a tree like structure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you example is correct, that is not valid XML. On the second case, opens tag1, opens tag2, closes tag1! There are libraries that try to guess malformed XML but please, first confirm your example is correct.

Comment: Also, post how you are trying to currently access the elements.

Comment: XML by definition is well-formed. This markup cannot be used in compliant XML libraries like etree. Now if this all wraps in root tags which you did not post then it may be valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one XML fragment per line, just parse each line individually.

```
for line in some_file:
    # parse using ET and getroot.
```